# Run Custom Tool not available to generate resources.designer.cs

Tags: visual-studio-2017

In my project on one computer with VS2017 Version 15.5.4 I have the ability to run a custom tool on Resources.resx

[image: this menu with the option to run a custom tool]

On another computer with VS2017 15.5.6 I have

[image: this menu without the option to run a custom tool]

The code is cloned from the same project

How can I get the custom tool working?

Answer (score 1):

Right click Resources.resx and select properties
then right click the Resources.resx file with the propeties window open. Run Custom tool is now available.

Answer (score 1):

Right click 'Resources.resx' and select properties then add in advanced->Custom Tool option this 'PublicResXFileCodeGenerator'. The Run Custom tool option is now available.